# Why google is not caching my pages?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, cache

Some pages of my website chevy-cars.com are showing the cache button on the right side of the links in google listing and some pages are not for a long time. The pages that are showing cache button are created in Wordpress and the pages that are not showing the cache button are created in laravel.

Showing cache:     site:chevy-cars.com

Not showing cache: site:chevy-cars.com/used-cars.

please help me out finding the reason.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem, but usual behavior of Google with sites having too volatile information. News sites, marketplaces and so on have usually no cache, because pages become too fast outdated. Google caches your page - but in an hour the car from this page is sold out. What should Google do?

In my experience marketplaces workout this on the following way:

- they create static categories, like `Chevrolet Camaro`, place content there and index them - such pages will be cached.
- Then they create some nested categories, like `Chevrolet Camaro, Model year 2000`, place some content there again and index them - such categories are cached too.
- Then they create car listing data files as JSON files, deindex them and show such listings through XHR on the corresponding category pages.

On this way they have clean indexed and cached categories with SEO content, but without car listing, which gets fast outdated (sold out)